# Text Segmentation Problem give Word Frequencies in a Universe

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, natural-language-processing

Given a dictionary of words and their frequencies (how many times they appear in a universe and given a string(no spaces, punctuation, etc.). What is the best way to segment into individual words? I believe a dynamic programming approach would be best. But I am not sure how to proceed about throwing away unnecessary prefixes of identified words and so on.

```
Ex. "theyouthevent" 

 could be "the you the vent"
 or "they out he vent"
 or "the youth event" (most likely)
```

I think Peter Norvig outlines a pretty good approach in this http://norvig.com/ngrams/ch14.pdf

Just curious to see if there are any other good approaches suited for the specific problem with the data I have. Norvig has n-gram data while I only have word frequencies (which is essentially a unigram)

Comment: Could you give minimal example, if possible with all problems that you encounter. say words are {cat, book, tea} , you are given string for example 'bookteabookcat'? If some words are prefixes of other words, but you have frequencies, would starting from words not being prefixes help?

Comment: Have you looked into suffix trees or suffix arrays?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: What's the function to optimize? You say one option is "most likely" -- but why?

Comment: This is asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26189292/47984